# Get MySQL privileges in a computer-readable format

Tags: php, mysql, privileges

So far, I know that I, as a human being, can check out my privileges by querying of `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER`. But now I would like my php software to be able to chech its privileges on its own, and this query doesn't really output something easy to manipulate through code :
"`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'`"
"`` GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `database`.* TO 'user'@'ip' ``"
"`GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'ip'`"
...and maybe other kind of format I don't know of.

Is it possible to easily recover an *actual array* of privileges for a specifc database? or do I need to come up with some tortured regex to parse these strings ?

Comment: you could look at how phpmyadmin does it.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mysql.user ` fetch and look at what's there. Maybe add a `WHERE User = 'something'` etc...

Comment: You can have a look at `information_schema.schema_privileges`, `information_schema.table_privileges`, `information_schema.column_privileges` and `information_schema.user_privileges`.